# jQuery: How to count table columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, how would you figure out how many columns are in a table?

```
<script>
    alert($('table').columnCount());
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>spans one column</td>
        <td colspan="2">spans two columns</td>
        <td colspan="3">spans three columns</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

The total number of columns in this example is 6. How could I determine this using jQuery?

Comment: Attaching an id to the row, looping through `HTMLTableRowElement.cells` for that row, and adding up the `colSpan` DOM property for each cell would probably get the job done. However, that's without jQuery.

Comment: How do you count six columns in your example?

Comment: When you say `6`, do you mean a `td` of `colspan="2"` would count as two?

Comment: Right, so if you have 5 rows, do you want a result of 6 or 30?

Comment: If a TD spans more than one column, then it counts as more than one column. A table cell does not necessarily = a column since a cell can span multiple columns.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Here you go:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/XQjFB/)

```
$(function() {
    var colCount = 0;
    $('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
            colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
        } else {
            colCount++;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: One note... I noticed that some examples work better when you make the first line of your function - $(this).find('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function() { ...

Comment: This also might need to be adjusted if the first row contains th elements instead of td. I used ('tr:last-child td')

Comment: When a table has thead and tbody, the code doesn't work.

Comment: You can replace the entire IF with just `colCount += this.colSpan;` which returns 1 when it's not set in the HTML. No point in using jQuery when the DOM already provides better functionality.

Answer (score 40):

```
$("table").find("tr:first td").length;
```

I edited as I didn't realize you were counting the colspan's.

If you want to include using colspan try a loop through the td's in the first row:

```
var cols = $("table").find("tr:first td");
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++)
{
   var colspan = cols.eq(i).attr("colspan");
   if( colspan && colspan > 1)
   {
      count += colspan;
   }else{
      count++;
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 because you left your original answer that doesn't involve column spans b/c that's what I needed now, almost two years later.  $('#myTable tr').length;

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Just to be clear: `$('#myTable tr').length;` will give you the number of _rows_ in the table, or rather the number of `tr` elements.

Comment: There may be tables within tables: `$("table > tbody").find("> tr:first > td").length`

Answer (score 35):

This is the cleanest in my opinion. It handles tables within tables. And is short and simple:

```
$("table > tbody > tr:first > td").length
```

Comment: short and smart answer.

Comment: This assumes that no cells have a `colspan` attribute, and also assumes that each `tr` has an identical number of `td` elements. Also, what about `th` elements?

Comment: Awesome dude.. This is really smart answer .

Comment: You`re genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In POJS (Plain Old JavaScript):

HTML:

```
<table id="foo">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td colspan="2">2</td>
            <td colspan="3">3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("foo"), i = 0, j = 0, row, cell, numCols = 0;
//loop through HTMLTableElement.rows (includes thead, tbody, tfoot)
for(i;i<foo.rows.length;i++)
{
    row = foo.rows[i];
    //loop through HTMLTableRowElement.cells
    for(j = 0;j<row.cells.length;j++)
    {
        cell = row.cells[j];
        numCols += cell.colSpan;
        cell = null;
    }
    row = null;
}

alert(numCols) //6;
```

[HTMLTableElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-64060425)[.rows](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6156016) will collect rows from every [HTMLTableSectionElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-67417573) (THead, TBody, and TFoot). Each section also has its own `rows` HTMLCollection, so you can filter them if need be.

Answer (score 4):

To be robust..I'd do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZErS7/)

```
alert(numCol("table") + " is the max number of cols");

function numCol(table) {
    var maxColNum = 0;

    var i=0;
    var trs = $(table).find("tr");

    for ( i=0; i<trs.length; i++ ) {
        maxColNum = Math.max(maxColNum, getColForTr(trs[i]));
    }

    return maxColNum;
}

function getColForTr(tr) {

    var tds = $(tr).find("td");

    var numCols = 0;

    var i=0;
    for ( i=0; i<tds.length; i++ ) {
        var span = $(tds[i]).attr("colspan");

        if ( span )
            numCols += parseInt(span);
        else {
            numCols++;
        }
    }
    return numCols;
}
```

Just in case we have some funkiness going on between different rows.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/WvN9u/

Just paying attention to `colspan attr`

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a table with something like $('foo#table') or $('table:first')

```
function getColumnCount(e) { //Expects jQuery table object
    var c= 0;
    e.find('tbody tr:first td').map(function(i,o) { c += ( $(o).attr('colspan') === undefined ? 1 : parseInt($(o).attr('colspan')) ) } );
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To circumvent the td/th issue (and also fix a potential issue where attr('colspan') was giving me strings) I went with this:

```
var colspan = 0;
$('#table').find('tr:first').children().each(function(){
    var cs = $(this).attr('colspan');
    if(cs > 0){ colspan += Number(cs); }
    else{ colspan++; }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Get number of columns in table.
 * @param {string} table jQuery selector
 * @param {boolean} [malformed=false] whether to inspect each row of malformed table;
 * may take some time for large tables
 * @returns {?number} number of columns in table, null if table not found.
 */
function getTableColumnsCount(table, malformed) {
    malformed = malformed || false;

    var $table = $(table);
    if (!$table.length) {
        return null;
    }

    var rows = $table.children('thead, tfoot, tbody').children('tr');
    if (!malformed) {
        // for correct tables one row is enough
        rows = rows.first();
    }
    var maxCount = 0;
    rows.each(function () {
        var currentCount = 0;
        $(this).children('th, td').each(function () {
            currentCount += this.colSpan;
        });
        maxCount = Math.max(maxCount, currentCount);
    });

    return maxCount;
}
```

See in action https://jsfiddle.net/kqv7hdg5.

- Takes `colspan` into account.
- Works for nested tables.
- Works for `<thead>`, `<tfoot>`, `<tbody>`.
- Works for mix of `<th>` and `<td>`.
- Works for malformed tables.

Slightly modified version for those who would like to pass jQuery object instead of selector https://jsfiddle.net/5jL5kqp5.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an ID to the header row:

```
<table>
    <tr id="headerRow">
        <td>spans one column</td>
        <td colspan="2">spans two columns</td>
        <td colspan="3">spans three columns</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then you can use the following function:

```
function getColumnCount(headerRowId) {
    var columnCount = 0;
    $('#' + headerRowId + ' > td').each(function() {
        var colspanValue = $(this).attr('colspan');
        if (colspanValue == undefined) {
            columnCount++;
        } else {
            columnCount = columnCount + parseInt(colspanValue);
        }
    });
    return columnCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified answer of Craig M.
And modified to apply to both td and th tag.

```
function GetColumnCount($Table)
{
    var ColCount = 0;
    $Table.find("tr").eq(0).find("th,td").each(function ()
    {
        ColCount += $(this).attr("colspan") ? parseInt($(this).attr("colspan")) : 1;
    });

    return ColCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = document.getElementById("price-test-table")
foo.tBodies["0"].firstElementChild.children.length
```

1. Give your table an id name
2. Assume your rows all have the same amount of columns and you have a table body
3. Use above code, which I think is the simplest on here, similar to first answer 
   but provides a little more detail

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery and reduce it could look like this:

```
$.fn.tableCellCount = function() {
    return $(this).find('tr:first td, tr:first th').get().reduce(function(a,b) {
        return a + ($(b).attr('colspan') ? parseInt($(b).attr('colspan')) : 1);
    },0)
}

$('table').tableCellCount();
```

Or even simpler:

```
$.fn.tableCellCount = function() {
    return $(this).find('tr:first td, tr:first th').get().reduce(function(a,b) {
        return a + (b.colSpan ? parseInt(b.colSpan) : 1);
    },0)
}

$('table').tableCellCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple solution I have done:
In case you are using **TR** change **TH** for **TR**.
Using JQUERY:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var number = $("table > tbody > tr:first > th").length;
            for(var i=0; i <= number; i++){
                $('th:nth-child('+ i +')').hide();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One Line:

```
$('.table-responsive tr th').children().length;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function(){
    num_columns = 0;
    $("table td]").each(function(){
        num_columns = num_columns + ($(this).attr('colspan') == undefined ? 1 : $(this).attr('colspan'));
    });
    return num_columns;
}
```

Comment: At least provide working syntax please, if not an alternative answer. Even without the syntax error, this just returns a string of colspan for every td in the table. Nothing useful.