# How to find a table's column count using the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

For row count using DOM, we have tablename.rows.length to get number of rows, but we don't have 'cols.length' for column count.

How can we find the number of columns (only using the DOM)?

Comment: Read this http://domenlightenment.com/

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use cells to calculate the column, assuming that the number of column of first row will be same for all

```
tablename.rows[0].cells.length;
```

Comment: i have to embed this, simple n short as I don't need colspans. thanks

Answer (score 7):

I would use the table's `rows` property and the first row's `cells` property and total the `colSpan` property of each cell in the row. This will work in all major browsers back to IE 4 and should be pretty fast.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gtdru/

Code:

```
function getTableColumnCount(table) {
    var columnCount = 0;
    var rows = table.rows;
    if (rows.length > 0) {
        var cells = rows[0].cells;
        for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; ++i) {
            columnCount += cells[i].colSpan;
        }
    }
    return columnCount;
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. jQuery version here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683882/jquery-how-to-count-table-columns

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such a concept in the DOM.

You could try and count the max number of `td` and `th` in `tr` :

```
var max = 0;
$('#tableId tr').each(function(){max=Math.max(max, $('td,th', this).length)});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/uLFsp/)

If you want to take into account the colspan, it's a little heavier :

```
var max = 0;
$('#tableId tr').each(function(){
    var inTr = 0;
    $('td,th', this).each(function() { inTr += parseInt($(this).attr('colspan')) || 1;});
    max = Math.max(max,inTr);
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/EdW4x/)

Comment: Very quick you are.. i was about to point you out that you are missing td in the function. +1 from my side

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will better try this

Answer (score 1):

This will work with complex table headers :

```
$($('#table_id_here tbody tr')[0]).find('td').length
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(function() {
    var colCount = 0;
    $('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('colspan')) {
            colCount += +$(this).prop('colspan');
        } else {
            colCount++;
        }
    });
    alert(colCount);
});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6CV9u/)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to get the number of possible cols in any table is using the following (vanillaJS) function:

```
/**
 * Calculates the number of columns based on any row using colSpan attribute.
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} table : The table element to be count.
 *
 * @return {int} The number of columns this table has.
 */
var getTableColSpan = function getTableColSpan(table) {

    var colSpan = 0; // initialize counter
    var trs = table.querySelectorAll('tr'); // get firt tr cells.

    for (var j = 0; j < trs.length; j++) {

        var tr = trs[j];
        var tds = tr.cells;

        var trColSpan = 0; // initialize counter

        // loops between columns and gets each one's colSpan
        for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; ++i) {
            trColSpan += tds[i].colSpan;
        }

        colSpan = trColSpan > colSpan ? trColSpan : colSpan;
    }

    return colSpan;
};
```