# Uniquely identify HTML table in order to count columns

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, count, dynamic-columns

I need to append columns to an HTML table in a specific location. [This topic discusses doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005376/append-columns-to-an-html-table-offsetting-from-right) - pretty handy! My problem is that the `columnCount()` function shown below does not have the ability to target a specific table. It counts all TDs present in the HTML which ends up causing problems when generating an index value.

```
function countColumn() {
   var colCount = 0;
   $('tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () {
       if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
           colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
       } else {
           colCount++;
       }
   });
   return colCount;
}
```

I have two JS fiddles.

- [One functions](http://jsfiddle.net/nYw25/14/) because there is only one table.
- [The second one](http://jsfiddle.net/eYYvv/4/) does not function because there are two tables present.

  The second fiddle returns an invalid `colCount` value and cannot place the column inside of the target table. I am still too green on selectors to be able to apply the correct selector in context... I am slowly learning this language.

**Edit:** [Link to the JSFiddle that has the corrected code.](http://jsfiddle.net/vxVzh/2/) I hope this helps someone else who is struggling with selector syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the table ID as a parameter:

```
function countColumn(tableID) {
   var colCount = 0;
   $('#' + tableID + ' tr:nth-child(1) td').each(function () {
       if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
           colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
       } else {
           colCount++;
       }
   });
   return colCount;
}
```

You could also define a jQuery method that operates on a selector:

```
$.fn.colCount = function() {
   var colCount = 0;
   $('tr:nth-child(1) td', this).each(function () {
       if ($(this).attr('colspan')) {
           colCount += +$(this).attr('colspan');
       } else {
           colCount++;
       }
   });
   return colCount;
};
```

Then you can do `var count = $("#someTable").colCount();`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! I've been struggling with selector syntax. Are there any good resources that outline how to select specific DOM elements - I find that I get lost without solid examples.

Comment: Thank you for humoring a newb :) Can't tell you how much I appreciate the help.